# Does Heroku support ActionController::Live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, server-sent-events

I have a Rails app hosted on Heroku and I want to add Server Sent Events functionalities, but I can't find any documentation or blog post specific for Heroku.

As not all servers (e.g. WEBrick) support ActionController::Live I was wondering what is the default server on Heroku and whether is possible to configure the environment (i.e. change server) to support SSEs.

Any further advice about the server to use and how to configure would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer is not so widely helpfull, but you can try.

For the first thing:

create [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) in rails root within the following content:

```
web: bundle exec rails server puma -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

then add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'puma'
```

In above you can switch to *thin*, but consider link below (and many more details)

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html

Answer (score 0):

Heroku wouldn't necessarily be the issue here - it's an environment which allows your app to run (on Amazon EC2 I think)

---

**Multi-Threaded Servers**

The thing you've got to look for is the server software you use to run your app. Heroku basically takes your server gem & allows it to run with their processors, and other computing power; so it's really whether their platform can play ball with the right server

You're really looking for multi-threaded servers, which you can find here [Is puma the ONLY multi-threaded rails 4 http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902386/is-puma-the-only-multi-threaded-rails-4-http-server)

> [Puma](http://puma.io/)
>
> [Rainbows!](http://rainbows.rubyforge.org/) supports multiple concurrency models, including multithreading
>
> [Zbatery](http://zbatery.bogomip.org/) - Rack HTTP server without a fork stuck in it
>
> [Phusion Passenger 4](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) has supported multithreading since its beta stages
>
> [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) does have a threaded mode which can be enabled by passing
> --threaded or by setting threaded: true in the appropriate configuration file (e.g. bundle exec thin start --threaded)
>
> [Net::HTTP::Server](https://github.com/postmodern/net-http-server), despite the lack of advertising, supports
> multithreading; very minimalist