# Is puma the ONLY multi-threaded rails 4 http server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, thin, puma

I've gotten our stack converted to Rails 4 (yea!)

and I'm looking to take advantage of the thread-safe code.

Puma works in getting up, stopping it appears to be a different problem :(

Is Puma the only multi-threaded rails?

```
Thin -> EventMachine
Unicorn -> Forking
Puma -> multi-threaded

Mongrel -> don't care
Webbrick -> don't care
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fall under the heading of "software tools commonly used by programmers" and thus not be "off-topic"?

Comment: I checked the about page - http://stackoverflow.com/about  possilby a bit in the grey area, but I think it qualifies.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No. In alphabetical order:

- **[`Iodine`](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine)** a HTTP / Websocket Server & EventMachine alternative (kqueue/epoll based)
- **[`Net::HTTP::Server`](https://github.com/postmodern/net-http-server)**, despite the lack of advertising, supports multithreading
- **[Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/)** has supported multithreading  [since v4 beta](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/08/03/why-rails-4-live-streaming-is-a-big-deal/)
- **[Rainbows!](http://rainbows.rubyforge.org/)** supports multiple concurrency models, including multithreading
- **[Reel](https://github.com/celluloid/reel/)** is a [Celluloid](http://celluloid.io/)-backed "evented" server, which "also works great for multithreaded applications and provides traditional multithreaded blocking I/O support too"
- **[Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)** has a threaded mode, which can be enabled by passing `--threaded` or by setting `threaded: true` in the appropriate configuration file (e.g. `bundle exec thin start --threaded`)
- **[WEBrick](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html)** is on its own multithreaded, so it's not fair to eliminate it as an option; if you're using the Rails-embedded version, you'll need to [monkey-patch `Rails::Server` to enable multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940926/504845)
- **[Zbatery](http://zbatery.bogomip.org/)** is based on Rainbows! and supports all concurrency models that Rainbows! supports

Note that currently ***MRI Ruby runs only one thread runs at a time*** due to its [global interpreter lock (GIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).  You'll only be truly able to exploit multithreading by using a different Ruby runtime such as [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) or [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/), which provide access to native threads. If you decide to go with JRuby, there are several [JVM-dependent servers worth exploring](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Servers).

Comment: Thank you!  This helped out a great deal

Comment: Another one for the list: [iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) also supports both multi-threading and multi-processes.

Comment: It's definitely multithreaded. See links above or the source code: https://github.com/nahi/webrick/blob/master/lib/webrick/server.rb

Comment: OMG, I just learned today that WEBrick is multi-threaded! And it doesn't even seem to perform bad.

Answer (score 1):

Trinidad is nice. A very powerful server for jRuby development:

http://blog.jruby.org/2012/04/two-apps-one-trinidad/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/377-trinidad?view=comments

Here are some good benchmarks (the Trini server beats puma):

http://carlhoerberg.github.io/blog/2012/03/31/jruby-application-server-benchmarks/

A nice Trinidad Server setup tutorial:

http://blog.jruby.org/2012/04/two-apps-one-trinidad/